# Create Password Protected File in Android

Tags: android, itext, android-file, android-pdf-api

I have to create a PDF, which will be downloaded from server and while saving in local memory or say SD Card, I have to create a password protected PDF File here, so what process should I follow here.
Please help me, need your guidance. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Check the MuPDF Library as example. https://mupdf.com/. After trying it yourself return here and create a new answer with a more elaborated question with a single problem, not as general as this one.

Comment: Thanks for the support.
But I want to set password on that PDF File. MuPDF is a PDF Viewer Library

Comment: The MuPDF has some functions to work with PDFs but I see it doesn't has the option you need. Check the this port of the Apache PDFBox to Android https://github.com/TomRoush/PdfBox-Android